# Append element to the last when it clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to detach the list with its content and append it to the last when it clicked i have trouble at appending it at the last

here is html for ul list and i want to detach the first child if the list when the link is clicked and make it at the last of the list

```js
var list = $('li.playing').detach();
var ctr = 0;
$('li').click(function(e) {
  if (ctr = 0) {
    $('li').append(list).show();
    list = $(this).detach();
  } else {
    list = $(this).detach();
  }
  $('li').append(list);
  $('li').siblings().removeClass('playing');
  $(this).addClass('playing');
});
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
}

li.playing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="playing">
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid1">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid1">Despacito (Song Cover by Sam Tsu) Live Love Party</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid2">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid2">All About that Base - Just Dance - Full Gameplay 5 Stars KINECT</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid3">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid3">Just Dance 2018: Side to Side - 5 stars</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid4">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid4">Twerk It Like Miley - The Fitness Marshall - Cardio Concert</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS part is for the display function of the list when it have `class='playing'` it will not appear  to html  and if `li` alone will be displayed

The Javascript part is my problem:
the firstchild if list is playong so i dont want it to appear in the same div rather hide it or detach it from the list and put put it at the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to detach, just directly `.append()` it to `.parent()`.

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('playing');
    $(this).addClass('playing');
    $(this).parent().append(this);
});

//Move current playing element to last
$('li.playing').appendTo('.tab-links');
```

```js
$('li').click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('playing');  
  $(this).addClass('playing');
  $(this).parent().append(this);
});

//Move current playing element
$('li.playing').appendTo('.tab-links');
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
}

li.playing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="playing">
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid1">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid1">Despacito (Song Cover by Sam Tsu) Live Love Party</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid2">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid2">All About that Base - Just Dance - Full Gameplay 5 Stars KINECT</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid3">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid3">Just Dance 2018: Side to Side - 5 stars</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="vidcon">
      <a href="#vid4">
        <div class="tumbnail">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="textlink">
        <a href="#vid4">Twerk It Like Miley - The Fitness Marshall - Cardio Concert</a>
        <p class="info">Duration: 00:10:00<br>1,234,567 views<br>2 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh  this is a great help but the first child is active so  want it to remove 1st the first child of the list and append to the last. . . thanks

Comment: @JustLeaveitBlank, Updated answer and please add share your name Mr. Blank. It must be beautiful

Comment: great thanks Mr. Satpal sorry for inconvenience . . . i only self studied it i have many difficulties at web development and our proctor doesn't attend class just putting activities on his facebook pages